# What is a single bar in python?

Tags: python, syntax, apache-beam

I was reading a [word count example for Apache beam](https://beam.apache.org/get-started/wordcount-example/) when I saw this Python code

```
p | beam.io.ReadFromText(
'gs://dataflow-samples/shakespeare/kinglear.txt')
```

In this `p` is a already defined variable

Ignoring the Apache beam part I am a bit confused from Python perspective. I have never seen this `|` in Python before. What is this language construct known as?

Comment: A bitwise OR operator ?

Comment: It is a duplicate but of this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43796046/explain-apache-beam-python-syntax/43812686#43812686