# How is pipe syntax implemented in apache beam?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, apache-beam

I am now studying `apache beam` and out of curiosity, I would like to ask below question.

In advance, I have read below documents and threads.

https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#applying-transforms

[Explain Apache Beam python syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43796046/explain-apache-beam-python-syntax)

I understand that pipe(`|`) is the python version of `.apply` of java. However, I  am curious to know how does python interpret `__or__` operator as processor which processes each pcollection element that goes through from left to right.

I appreciate if someone could educate me and point me the reference of code.

Thanks,
Yu

Comment: I did a Google search on "python operator overloading" and found a bunch of good references that seem likely.   Searching the Github repository, it looks likely that this may be the actual code:

https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/sdks/python/apache_beam/transforms/ptransform.py#L470

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would like to mark @Kolban 's reply as answer.

> I did a Google search on "python operator overloading" and found a
>   bunch of good references that seem likely. Searching the Github
>   repository, it looks likely that this may be the actual code: 
>   https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/sdks/python/apache_beam/transforms/ptransform.py#L470

Answer (score 0):

It does so via [operator overloading](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/9bceff5a6e587ece0177cdbd1b4caa3646130ae2/sdks/python/apache_beam/transforms/ptransform.py#L506):

```
def __or__(self, right):
  """Used to compose PTransforms, e.g., ptransform1 | ptransform2."""
  if isinstance(right, PTransform):
    return _ChainedPTransform(self, right)
  return NotImplemented
```

Piping (|) is used to compose *PTransforms*, e.g., `ptransform1 | ptransform2`.