# What is pipe | and >> in python?

Tags: python, apache-beam

Recently I'm learning apache beam, and find some python code like this:

```
lines = p | 'read' >> ReadFromText(known_args.input)

  # Count the occurrences of each word.
  def count_ones(word_ones):
    (word, ones) = word_ones
    return (word, sum(ones))

  counts = (lines
            | 'split' >> (beam.ParDo(WordExtractingDoFn())
                          .with_output_types(unicode))
            | 'pair_with_one' >> beam.Map(lambda x: (x, 1))
            | 'group' >> beam.GroupByKey()
            | 'count' >> beam.Map(count_ones))
```

From: https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/sdks/python/apache_beam/examples/wordcount.py#L92

What is the syntax and usage of `|` and `>>` in python?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pipe character in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5988665/pipe-character-in-python), also [>> operator in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3411749), also [Explain Apache Beam python syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43796046/explain-apache-beam-python-syntax)

Comment: This looks like the behaviour of the operators is overwritten. What they do (now) shoulds be found in the library's documentation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default `|` stands for the logical or bit-wise *OR* operator, and `>>` for right shift, but fortunately you can overload operators in Python. So in order to have custom definition for `|` and `>>,` you just have to overload the two following dunder(magic) methods in your class [`__or__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__or__) and [`__rshift__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__rshift__):

```
class A():
    def __or__(self):
        pass
    def __rshift__(self):
        pass
```

I recommend you to read more about [Python Data Model](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html).

Now Looking on the Beam Python SDK, `__or__` is overloaded in the `PTransform` class:

```
  def __or__(self, right):
    """Used to compose PTransforms, e.g., ptransform1 | ptransform2."""
    if isinstance(right, PTransform):
      return _ChainedPTransform(self, right)
    return NotImplemented
```

Comment: this is the best explanation I found so far. It's 2021 now - and still no human-readable documentation from Google explaining their Dataflow syntax... I guess the assumption is that those willing to use it will happily read Apache Beam source code to understand what it is doing :))

Comment: docs here https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#transforms